# how to extract sub domain from list

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a list like the below example and am looking for a way to extract the sub-domains if applicable.

```
10.1.55.2 router1.local.com
192.168.1.5 server1
192.168.1.6 server2.local
```

How can I use awk, sed, or a similar tool take the above list and end up with a list like the below?

```
router1
server1
server2
```

I'm fairly novice to bash scripting so I'm looking for a place to start.  Thanks!

Comment: In the general case, you need a tool which knows your local domain hierarchy. For the public internet domain hierarchy, see http://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 2):

I'd say

```
awk '{ sub(/\..*/, "", $2); print $2 }' hosts
```

This cuts off everything after the first period from the second field and prints the result.

Addendum: Since there may be more than one hostname in a `hosts` file line, and to exclude comment lines, you might want to use

```
awk '!/^#/ { for(i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) { sub(/\..*/, "", $i); print $i } }' hosts
```

to catch them all.

Comment: Great! Thank you. These both address what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^[^ ]* \|\..*//g' file
router1
server1
server2
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk '{ split($2,a,/\./); print a[1] }' file
router1
server1
server2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/#/{print $2}' hosts | awk -F"." '{print $1}'
```

which ignores lines with # characters in it

Comment: note this could be condensed in one or two commands instead of four: `cat file | grep` can be just `grep file`. Also, `grep -v "#" | awk` can be `awk '!/#/ `...

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I could reduce it to something like this: `awk '!/#/{print $2}' hosts | awk -F"." '{print $1}'`

Comment: So go ahead and edit it to have a better answer :) You can probably tweak awk to make it without any pipes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash version:

```
while read ip host; do echo ${host%%.*}; done < list
```

The `${host%%.*}` expression strips everything from the end of the string to the first period.